# Ubuntu 22.04 i2c

Tags: touchscreen, i2c

I have install Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on my Asus T300
Kernel:

```
Linux sea-console 5.19.0-43-generic #44~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon May 22 13:39:36 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

However, the touchscreen is not working.

output of dmesg | grep i2c

```
[    0.668867] i2c_dev: i2c /dev entries driver
[    0.960329] i2c_hid_acpi i2c-INVN6500:00: unexpected HID descriptor bcdVersion (0xf2ab)
[    0.960349] i2c_hid_acpi i2c-INVN6500:00: Failed to fetch the HID Descriptor
[    0.991187] i2c i2c-1: 2/2 memory slots populated (from DMI)
[    5.093049] inv-mpu6050-i2c i2c-INVN6500:00: mounting matrix not found: using identity...
[    5.093057] inv-mpu6050-i2c i2c-INVN6500:00: supply vdd not found, using dummy regulator
[    5.093100] inv-mpu6050-i2c i2c-INVN6500:00: supply vddio not found, using dummy regulator
[    5.625062] i2c i2c-0: Added multiplexed i2c bus 2
```

1. I have disabled wayland.
2. It feels like ubuntu can see the device, but just not receiving any inputs.

xinput output

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech MX Master                        id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech MX Master 3                      id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04 Mouse id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04   id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Wireless Radio Control               id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ CASUE CASUE USB Keyboard                  id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ CASUE CASUE USB Keyboard Consumer Control id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ CASUE CASUE USB Keyboard System Control   id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD           id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04 Stylus    id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech MX Master                        id=21   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech MX Master 3                      id=22   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```